# Incompatibility between some android libraries and google play services

Tags: android, google-play-services, arcgis, android-support-design

I use the following libraries in build.gradle (app), and there some libraries in libs folder such as: "Arcgis SDK and ksoap2 and gcm.jar" in android-studio project, when I builds it, causes the following error:

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'. com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_66\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

this is the build.gradle (app):

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 'Google Inc.:Google APIs:23'
    buildToolsVersion '23.0.2'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.eywa.paltrack"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
   }
   buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
   }
   packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/LGPL2.1'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'

   }

}

dependencies {
     compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
     testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
     compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
     compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
     compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.3.0'

}
```

And when I remove (Arcgis SDK) or (com.android.support:design) or (com.google.android.gms:play-services) when I remove one of them the project builds successfully. and I need all of them. can you help me about this problem?

Comment: How much methods has the arcgis SDK? Google Play Services has above 56k methods. That is not far away from the 65K dex limit. Furthermore, do you have any more specific error?

Comment: how to know how much methods arcgis SDK has ?

Comment: I don't have any more specific error this error occurs at compile time,
If you create new android project and use all this libraries the error occurs,
I tries it for new project.

Comment: There are several tools outside to count the methods. The most easy one: www.methodscount.com/ But it doesn't support every lib. Other tools are https://github.com/KeepSafe/dexcount-gradle-plugin or https://github.com/mihaip/dex-method-counts

Comment: Why do you need the whole play services stuff? E.g. If you only need google maps then use the specific map-dependency: compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.3.0'

Comment: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_66\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 3

Comment: @TawfiqDawod which feature of play service you wants to add in your app ? based on that add it like for map `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:7.3.0'`

Comment: I want to add it to use gcm notifications

Comment: For gcm you could use this dependency:   com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.3.0

Comment: yes, the problem solved if I do in the best answer below or when I replace the:  play-services:8.3.0 to  play-services-gcm:8.3.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding the described error in your comments:

```
"java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'. > com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_66\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 3 "
```

Add this section to the android-section in your build.gradle:

```
android {

   dexOptions {
     javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
   }
```

We are facing the problem, after updating to gradle-plugin 1.5.0. This solved our problem.